# Two exact copies of folder using FTP

Tags: backup, sync, ftp, windows-backup

I'm looking for any solution that will allow me under Windows to emulate functionallity similar to Dropbox or rsync using FTP protocol only.

What I need, is any piece of software (good enough in your opinion) that I will be able to run periodically and that will assure that `source` and `destination` are identical:

- all files on both sides copied to both sides,
- if two files of the same name exists, copy newest version of a file to both sides,
- delete on one side all files that are missing on another one.

Of course, this software must support iteration on all subfolders of both source and destination, for this to work succesfully -- there will be a large directory structure on both sides.

I've tried many backups solutions, but most of them failed, because being unable to create exact duplicate copy of both sides and offering incremental backup instead. For long time a Cobian Backup was on under my cosideration, but either I can't configure it correctly or it fails completely on re-creating destination on source (i.e. provides one-way backup only, without any way to have two exact duplicates).

I was advised to use Unison and give it a good try. This really looks good, but it uses SSH. I have a real trouble estabilishing SSH from my Windows computer to one of destinations (cygwin port failed to many times) and beside this, one of my destinations does not support SSH at all -- i.e. FTP access is the only available way.

The perfect solution for me would be something that I can run (command-line or  configuration) like this:

```
something.exe path/to/local/folder ftp://user:pass@111.11.11.1/path/to/folder
```

If it does exists at all...

Comment: Hope somebody has some experience with something, but other than that, there seem to be many programs, try googling for FTP synchronization, you can add command line, it seems to offer many things to try. If you find something and get it to work, then you could answer your own question with any relevant obstacle overcome or good thing to know, regarding the program and how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the windows version of [lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru/) to work.

- Download lftp from http://redpark.posterous.com/lftp-for-windows
- Unzip in a directory
- Run from the command line `lftp -c "open ftp://user:pass@your.ftp.com;your mirror ftp steps in here"`

See this copied mirror example from [a serverfault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/24833/56846):

```
lftp -c "set ftp:list-options -a;
open ftp://user:password@your.ftp.com; 
lcd ./web;
cd /web/public_html;
mirror --reverse --delete --use-cache --verbose --allow-chown  
--allow-suid --no-umask --parallel=2 --exclude-glob .svn"
```

For some reason the multiline did not work on my Windows 7 cmd.exe, had to make it a single line to execute correctly.

For more information on the mirror options, start the `lftp.exe` from the command line and type `mirror help`

Comment: Thanks! I surely give it a try and share here my opinion. +1 for your answer already. If it will be usable then I'll for sure choose it.